# Symfony2 Subdomain Routing - Different Bundles

Tags: php, symfony

**EDIT**
There is now the possibility of doing this in symfony 2.2

```
PlatformFooBundle:
    resource: "@PlatformFooBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    domain: foo.testdomain.com

PlatformBarBundle:
    resource: "@PlatformBarBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    domain: bar.testdomain.com

PlatformBazBundle:
    resource: "@PlatformBazBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    domain: baz.testdomain.com
```

You can use parameters in the domain as well

**EDIT OVER**

Before marking this as a duplicate, read on

http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/08/symfony2-locale-on-subdomains-not-on-the-url-path/

I've read this article, but it doesnt help me do what im trying to do.

i have 3 different applications that are running on the same domain name, with seperate subdomains. Currently, theya re all running in their own symfony install, and i'd like to get rid of that.

```
foo.testdomain.com
bar.testdomain.com
baz.testdomain.com
```

each of these use different bundles

```
PlatformFooBundle
PlatformBarBundle
PlatformBazBundle
```

and they each have their own route definitions.

basically, what i want is this

```
PlatformFooBundle:
    resource: "@PlatformFooBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    subdomain: www|devwww

PlatformBarBundle:
    resource: "@PlatformBarBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    subdomain: bar|devbar

PlatformBazBundle:
    resource: "@PlatformBazBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
    subdomain: baz|devbaz
```

how do i go about doing this?

Comment: I'm running a similar setup. Are you sharing the vendor dir between the apps?

Comment: yeah, we have our own internal library, where we put external libs fort hings like Symfony's core. Me modified the bin/vendor file and everything to update each of the apps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3378) going on to add this feature.

Comment: This would be awesome. Hopefully it goes in to 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ExperiumDomainedRoutingBundle](https://github.com/experium/ExperiumDomainedRoutingBundle), which is working really well for me. I haven't added a Bundle-wide domain route (only per controller using annotations), but I would expect that work as well.

Example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="frontend_show", options = {"domain_pattern"="{username}.%base_domain%"})
 * @Route("/u/{username}", name="private_show")
 * @Template("SiteBundle:Frontend:show.html.twig")
 */
```